# Consistently getting error from PHP registraton form

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I want this form to post information to a MySQL database. After modifying it a few times, my error message I implemented  `if(mysql_affected_rows()< 1)` (line 182) keeps appearing. Ironically, I don't know why.

It might be because at first I only had input fields, but then later I added a select field and I guess PHP might not know how to add that stuff to the database.

Code is [here](http://pastebin.com/LLYznYMJ).

Comment: Care to share the error message with us?

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before you added a select field, and now it does not work, go make sure your select field's name and value are showing up in $_POST. If you're requiring that field in mysql and its not there, then it would throw an error.

By the way, paste the form too since you said it was maybe related to that.